# Convert pandas timedelta to be displayed in seconds

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I was working on re-formatting some data in a dataframe and I needed to calculate a value for a new timedelta column which I did by subtracting start date of event with the start date when series is shifted up one row:

```
data['DURATION_NEW'] = (data['START'] - data['START'].shift(-1))
```

This work fine and creates a timedelta column, but the data there are in a very strange format:

```
foo['DURATION_NEW']
Out[80]: 
0      -1 days +23:53:30
1      -1 days +15:35:00
2      -1 days +23:50:00
3      -1 days +23:49:00
4      -1 days +23:53:30
      
1459   -1 days +23:47:00
1461   -1 days +23:51:00
1462   -1 days +22:08:01
1463   -1 days +23:39:30
1464                 NaT
Name: DURATION_NEW, Length: 1406, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I need to somehow convert this data to be displayed in seconds. First I tried to convert it to a datetime, but for some reason got an error that `dtype timedelta64[ns] cannot be converted to datetime64[ns]`.

Next I tried to manually re-convert it while specifying that I want it to be in seconds:

```
foo['DURATION_NEW'] = pd.to_timedelta(foo['DURATION_NEW'], unit='sec')
```

That didn't work either. All stays exactly as it is now.

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `total_seconds()` method on the `dt` accessor:

```
foo['DURATION_NEW'].dt.total_seconds()
```

Comment: another way is to use `np.timedelta64` i.e `(df['START'] - df['START'].shift(-1)) / np.timedelta64(1,'s')` this gives you access to other timedelta's as well. note to OP