# How to calculate total running hours/ minutes/seconds of timestamps in a python pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Dataframe with start and stop times of a motor. My end goal is to calculate how many total minutes, hours or seconds my motor has been running. I've been able to calculate the elapsed time by subtracting stop from start time and put them in a new column ELAPSED_TIME. Now I'm having difficulties getting the sum of my elapsed time. I would like to create a TOTAL column with the value 00:00:48 as per my sample data.

```
START                    STOP                      ELAPSED_TIME 
2020-08-23 11:52:04.587  2020-08-23 11:52:13.407   00:00:09
2020-08-23 12:52:02.703  2020-08-23 12:52:11.420   00:00:09
2020-08-23 13:52:01.840  2020-08-23 13:52:15.060   00:00:14 
2020-08-23 14:51:59.200  2020-08-23 14:52:14.577   00:00:16
```

My code currently looks like this with this error.

```
df_values["TOTAL"] = df_values["ELAPSED_TIME"].sum()
```

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'datetime.time'
```

My dataType currently looks like this `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>` and I tried `pd.to_datetime` to change it but it didn't work.

Comment: Writing total to a new column is meaningless because there will be only one value. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert pandas timedelta to be displayed in seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64600764/convert-pandas-timedelta-to-be-displayed-in-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do further computation on datetimes/timedeltas it's best to leave them in the correct type until the end as `str` type data will not behave as desired:

```
# Convert START and STOP to_datetime if not already
df['START'] = pd.to_datetime(df['START'])
df['STOP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['STOP'])

# Calculate Duration and round up to second (to match OP)
df['ELAPSED TIME'] = (df['STOP'] - df['START']).dt.ceil('S')

# Calculate Sum
df['TOTAL'] = df['ELAPSED TIME'].sum()
```

References:

- [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)
- [dt.ceil](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.ceil.html)
- [Series.sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html)

`df`:

```
                    START                    STOP    ELAPSED TIME           TOTAL
0 2020-08-23 11:52:04.587 2020-08-23 11:52:13.407 0 days 00:00:09 0 days 00:00:48
1 2020-08-23 12:52:02.703 2020-08-23 12:52:11.420 0 days 00:00:09 0 days 00:00:48
2 2020-08-23 13:52:01.840 2020-08-23 13:52:15.060 0 days 00:00:14 0 days 00:00:48
3 2020-08-23 14:51:59.200 2020-08-23 14:52:14.577 0 days 00:00:16 0 days 00:00:48
```

Comment: Hi Henry, I've changed start and stop columns to datetime and rounded ELAPSED_TIME  up to seconds, but I'm getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time' when I sum my total column. But I noticed ELAPSEDTIME is type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> So I changed ELAPSED_TIME to  datetime but now I'm getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: This is example works without modification. ELAPSED TIME _must_ be a Series of values. That is how all columns in a DataFrame are defined. It's why Series methods work. Also these are _not_ time values these are Durations (timedelta). Again the entire point of the answer is "do not convert away from the useable type until you're done doing computation".